# what is the code for error message for existing value while inputting in to data base using java spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What is the code for error message for existing value while inputting data in to data base using java spring framework?

I tried this code..

```
public class SkipCheckingListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {    
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        String exitCode = stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode();
        if (!exitCode.equals(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()) && 
              stepExecution.getSkipCount() > 0) {
            return new ExitStatus("COMPLETED WITH SKIPS");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

About your question: `ExitStatus` is just a string used to control job flow in your job xml definition and there isn't a predefined `ExitStatus` for duplicated data.

In spring-batch (your code is from this module of spring) duplicated data is a business concern so you have to manage it using a custom exception (as `DuplicatedOrderException` for example or a `DataAccessException` descendant) and use `no-rollback-exception-classes` in tasklet tag or `skippable-exception-classes` in chunk; adding a `SkipListener` and manage skip element as you want (maybe setting a step variabile).
In `StepExecutionListener.afterStep` you can check your previously variable and return a custom error message.